# I have a white icon - how to make it black without replacing it with CANVAS? It is a .png icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am looking for a script/library that I can use to apply a filter to some of my icon images. They are white and I want them to be black instead. I have some limitations:

- I can't create a new png for it
- I can't change the implementation (so I can't use other icons like FontAwesome etc)
- I must use the same `<img>` element so I cannot make use of `<canvas>`. So somehow I want the new, transformed image to have the exact structure as the replaced image.

So far I have tried [Filtrr](http://alexmic.net/filtrr/) and [Caman](http://camanjs.com/) but they use `<canvas>` elements. [fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/) does the same.

Do you know any other method to achieve this? It must work in Firefox/Chrome/Safari so no IE. CSS is also accepted instead of JavaScript, but as I know and tested, using `filter: invert` in CSS does not work in Firefox.

Thanks!

---

**Example**: I don't know how useful an example can be in my situation, but here it is:

I have this:

```
<div class="icon">
    <img src="myicon.png" data-activepath="activemyicon.png">
</div>
```

`myicon.png` is a white icon and I want to make it black in the browser. How can I achieve this (using CSS or JS) and keep the same HTML structure and elements?

---

**FIX:**
Please note that there are 2 answers that fixed this problem. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer. So here they are:

- [the CSS version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213982/1769650)
- [the JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26214107/1769650)

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: Done! I also fixed the title, there was a mistake.

Comment: Not all `filter`s work in Firefox, but some of them do :) Can you explain why you can't use FontAwesome?

Comment: @Rvervuurt obviously because I have a special set of icons that FontAwesome does not contain. Do you know any `filter` that solves this situation in Firefox?

Comment: As an aside, IcoMoon supports custom icon sets you upload yourself. That said, depending on how far back you need to support, you can use the greyscale filter to achieve something similar to what you're looking for. Something like, `greyscale(1)`. See: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Comment: Ah ok, that explains why you can't use FA ;) Maybe you can achieve it with drop-shadow and hiding the image afterwards? No offset, no blur, just a drop-shadow? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow() (I don't know which filters work or don't work in Firefox, Drop-shadow may be one that doesn't work)

Comment: @Rvervuurt yes, drop-shadow is one that does not work.

Comment: @MSost thanks, I'll take a look at IcoMoon and see if that's a solution. Regarding your second suggestion, like I said, that filter does not work in Firefox.

Comment: I understand that you cannot replace your `<img>` elements with `<canvas>` elements, but surely you could use a canvas element that you never append to the page, perform what you need to perform, and then put the image data into the `<img>` element?

Comment: @MS_SL It is exactly what does the script I gave [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26214107/3702797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need to support IE you can use this CSS filter:

```
.icon img{
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'invert\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#invert");
  -webkit-filter:invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

that will work with the current version of firefox too.

Comment: actually i can see it working in firefox 32.0.3
here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qm4hqqc/) for your tests

Comment: You are right, I accepted this as the answer since it's less "heavy" than the JS version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why you can't use `canvas` while you can change js.
So, **if you can save your icon on the server**, could you try this code :

```
function changeImgColor(img) {
    var can = document.createElement('canvas');
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var c = 255;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        if (data[i] == c && data[i + 1] == c && data[i + 2] == c) {
            data[i] = 0;
            data[i + 1] = 0;
            data[i + 2] = 0;
        }

        // overwrite original image
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }
    var newdata = can.toDataURL("image/png");
    img.src = newdata;
}
changeImgColor(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
```

**check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwsnwLn4/1)**

*Ps : you may have to hit "run" in order to load icons in results*

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answers my question. I hope I didn't waste too much of your time.

Comment: One more thing though... How can I send as a parameter all my icons that need to be converted without applying another class on them? Their selector in jquery would be like this `$(".item .icon img")`, but apparently I cannot use `document.querySelectorAll('.stopover .icon img')` instead of your `getElementsByTagName` function. It says: `TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement.`

Comment: I think it's because `querySelectorAll`returns a `NodeList`. You may try with `document.getElementsByClassName('stopover icon img')[0]`

Comment: Hum actually it does work with NodeLists too. Do you still use `[0]` ? Because the first node with `.icon`class is your div so you have to change to `document.querySelectorAll('.stopover .icon img')[1]`. You should log to console your query.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a bit of a change to your original idea, but have you considered using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) instead? It will be way quicker to change font color than to redraw images.

Comment: Thanks for responding but like I said, I cannot change the implementation method. FontAwesome is a great asset but it does not help me in this case. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It will work only chrome.

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);

}
```